# EF Core: support for collections of value objects

Tags: entity-framework-core, nhibernate, domain-driven-design

Anyone knows it the latest version of EF Core supports value object collections? Ie, can the following NH mapping code be translated into EF:

```
HasMany(employee => employee.Contactos)
                .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
                .AsBag()
                .Table("Employees")
                .KeyColumn("EmployeeId")
                .Component(ct => {
                               ct.Map(c => c.ContactKind, "ContactKindId")
                                 .CustomType(typeof(ContactKind))
                                 .CustomSqlType("bigint");
                               ct.Map(c => c.Value, "Contact");
                           })
                .Cascade.All()
                .Not.LazyLoad();
```

In practice, NH will delete and reinsert all contacts when performing an update operation for employees (entity which is the aggregate for the operation).

I'm assuming the answer is still no, but I'd really love to be proved wrong...

Thanks.